# How to find best knot for non-linear model

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I want to find out the best knot placement for my `gam` model. Here are the codes:

```
s<-c(3:20)
n<-1
aic<-0
kt<-""
for(i in s){g<-gam(data$y~data$x1+ 
s(data$t,bs="cr",k=i)+as.factor(data$DOW),family=poisson
               ,method="REML")
aic[n]<-AIC(g)
kt[n]<-paste("A",i)
n<-n+1
}
result<-data.frame(aic,kt)
result
```

I got a list of AICs of each model with 3 to 20 knots. Then I tried to get the scatter plot of AIC vs knots. The code:

```
plot(s,aic, xlab="number of knot",ylab="AIC",main="AIC~no.of knot")
```

The plot does not look like a U shape, so I increased the number of knots, 3:50 and then 3:100. But still they were not close to a U shape. AIC is decreasing up to the number of knots=20. Then it remains constant for the next increasing knots.  [here is the plot][1]

Edited:
To solve this I tried cross-validation on this `gam` model with this code:

```
 library(caret)
 b<-
 train(data$y~data$x1+data$t+data$DOW,method = "gam",family="poisson",
 na.action = na.pass,
 trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV", number = 1, repeats = 1),
 tuneGrid = data.frame(method = "GCV.Cp", select = FALSE))
```

The problem is that it shows an error, as y contains several missing values. I am new with GAMs, mgcv, and cross validation. Can anyone help me with the codes?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuAD.png

Comment: Have you considered cross validation?

Comment: [Wood (2017; pages 169–172)](https://www.crcpress.com/Generalized-Additive-Models-An-Introduction-with-R-Second-Edition/Wood/p/book/9781498728331) advocates for using GCV rather than AIC to select the smoothing parameter. Also, `?choose.k` provides some helpful information.

Comment: This really isn't a specific programming question. If you have general questions about using statistical models, you should ask over at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I will try cross-validation.